# how do i defer loading certain images so the page loads faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

this [page](http://seersuckermag.com/whitewashed/) is very image heavy and takes a solid amount of time to load as a result.

I'm wondering how I would defer loading everything in divs with these classes

```
<div class="image_holder">
    <img class="image" src="images/5pointz_cans.jpg" alt="Whitewashed: Destroying The Graffiti Mecca">
    <div class="caption2"> 
        <p>Abandoned spray cans at 5Pointz. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="before_after_slider">
    <div class="photo">
        <div class="after">
            <img src="center_before.jpg" width="1000px" height="600px"  alt="after" />
        </div>
        <div class="before">
            <img src="center_after.jpg" width="1000px" height="600px" alt="before" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="caption">
    <p>Roll over the photo with your cursor to see the before/after images. </p>
</div>
```

and then start once everything else has loaded, start loading everything in these divs.

Comment: First thing to do is use something like the Chrome "Timeline" tool to see where time is being taken while loading your site. Don't guess.

Comment: Load the images in JavaScript?

Comment: I think you should look into "Lazy Loading".

Comment: yes as @TalhaMasood said try lazy loading.. check this out: http://toddmotto.com/echo-js-simple-javascript-image-lazy-loading/

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: @Pointy good call. here is the [waterfall](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140104_V6_HJ7/1/details/)

Comment: I think the main problem with that page is that it's loading **27** big images, several megabytes worth.  The browser *already* loads those concurrently when it can, so moving the image loading to the background in JavaScript would have to be done really carefully in order for it to help.

Comment: A lot of those images are larger than they need to be; the page scales them down in size. That's really wasteful.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the tips. Any ideas on how to compress them best? I'm trying to keep them at 1000px wide so it looks good on bigger screens. thanks!

Comment: Well you can compress them with Gimp or Photoshop or whatever; there's no point sending pixels down the wire when you're just going to throw them away at the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can defer image loading using jQuery plugin, but there are some options that you should consider before:

### Use browser cache

You can speed up future download caching the image and making a fine tuning of .`htaccess` file:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
```

### Compress/Scale the images

Nothing to add at this point. :)

### Create CSS sprites

Using somethinh like [Spriteme](http://spriteme.org/)).

### [Lazy load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<img class="lazy" data-original="img/example.jpg" width="640" height="480">
...
$(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

### Defer javascript loading

You can use `defer` attribute to lazy load the external javascript file:

```
<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>
```